# Jenkins package project out of his workspace

Tags: maven, jenkins

I tried to build maven war projects with Jenkins.

Jenkins pulls the code and builds the project. However, the build is not in the workspace, but rather in a folder with the project source. I think Jenkins takes the target folder from maven pom file and builds it.

How can I tune Jenkins to make a build and deploy pipeline?

In the deploy phase Jenkins cannot find war file.

OS is windows, IDE - eclipse.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>my.test.webapp</groupId>
<artifactId>webApp</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>webApp</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <directory>${basedir}\target</directory> <!-- tried with this line and without -->
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Supply your Maven POM file. Jenkins just executes your process, it doesn't define it. If your POM file is hardcoding the path to something, there is no reason it would automatically appear in Jenkin's workspace.

Comment: Tried <directory>target</directory> - same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I coped with a problem:
In pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <baseFolder>${basedir}</baseFolder>
</properties>
<build>
    <directory>${baseFolder}/target</directory>
</directory>
```

In Jenkins run build maven build with properties

```
baseFolder=$WORKSPACE
```